# External table how to delete newline char from the end of each row

Tags: sql, oracle

i have problem with loading rows from a file, the point is that when im using External table like this

```
create table table_name
(
  id VARCHAR2(60)
)
organization external
(
  type ORACLE_LOADER
  default directory DIRECTORY
  access parameters 
  (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET EE8MSWIN1250 nobadfile nodiscardfile
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LDRTRIM
    REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
    (
      ID VARCHAR2(60)
    )
  )
  location ('tmp.txt')
)
reject limit 0;
```

my all rows have the newLine byte at the end of row, only thing that works is after loading data from file is update all rows using this

```
update table_name
set id = translate (id, 'x'||CHR(10)||CHR(13), 'x');
```

How can i make it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check exactly what newline charcters are in your file and than define the record delimiter explicitely.

Example

```
 records delimited by '\r\n'
```

The probable cause of your problem is that the newline character is not compatible with your operating system - which topic you can address as well.

Answer (score 0):

while may have line delimiter as either \n or \r\n.. 
you can check that by opening file in notepad++ or any other supporting editor and by clicking show all characters

based no how the data is in the life you may create the external table as

```
 RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\r\n'  or
 RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\n'  etx
```